# Отваливается Wi-Fi при работе в локальной сети через Teamviewer

Tags: windows-10, wifi, mikrotik, teamviewer

Периодически работаю в локальной сети Wi-Fi (MikroTik) с компьютерами на Windows 10 через Teamviewer. Проблема в том, что именно в это время либо отваливается Wi-Fi (на самом MikroTik), либо он начинает перезагружаться.

Если кто сталкивался подскажите куда копать?

Teamviewer 15.1 (лицензия).

Comment: Зачем TeamViewer в локальной сети? Почему не RDP, например?

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama редакция винды не позволяет мб? хотя какой-то удаленный помощник вроде везде был

Comment: Поддержку клиентов через RDP не очень удобно делать. Использую VNC и Teamviewer. В этом вопросе и описал проблему которую заметил с Teamviewer.

Comment: Использование wi-fi у микротика мне кажется в этом проблема, не знаю какая у вас модель, но у нашего модуль был никакой по этому я сразу от такого wi-fi отказался и вот вам совет, поставьте лучше промежуточный нормальный wi-fi роутер, ну или другой и проверьте работу.

Comment: @RifmaMan, не спорю, возможно проблема в Wi-Fi, какой нормальный роутер, из своего опыта, можете посоветовать?

Comment: @Highlander9 если учитывать обычный домашний сегмент я всем советую выбор из новой линейки Keenetic от ZyXEL (хотя сейчас они стоят не дешево так скажем), у меня дома стоит Keenetic Extra II, который качает фильмы через transmission (торрент) и раздает их в сеть по DLNA, у него хорошая OS которая удобна в настройке, стабильна и обновляется, также можно подключиться через инет по бесплатному домену 3-го уровня через вэб интерфейс или приложение для смарта. На счет корпоративного сегмента не подскажу к сожалению, уже давно не работаю с администрированием компьютерного парка.